# React-Router v5 history.push does not trigger the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm sorry my friends for asking this again. I found couple of solution for the issue. But they are very confused me. I just want to ask elegant way to do that. As you understand by the title, I have an issue about routing on react. Let me explain.

I have a button which name is `Login`. Once click the button I did some logic then I want to redirect to another view.

**Login.jsx** (just history part)

```
  import { withRouter } from "react-router";
.
.
.
.
  const {history} = this.props;
  if (history) history.push("/home");

.
.
.
.
export default (withRouter(Login));
```

App.js (limited part)

```
import {withRouter} from 'react-router';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch} from "react-router-dom";
.
.
.
.
.
<div className={'container-fluid'}>
                <Router>

                    <Route path="/login" exact component={Login}/>

                    {(showMe && !pathLogin) &&
                    <Header maximize={maximize}/>
                    }
                    {(showMe && !pathLogin) &&
                    <div className="row h-100">
                        <Sidebar maximize={maximize}/>

                        <Switch>
                            <Route path="/home" exact component={Home}/>
                            <Route path="/somepage" exact component={Somepage}/>
                        </Switch>
                    </div>
                    }
                </Router>
            </div>
.
.
.
.
export default (withRouter(App));
```

This structure is working fine. When I run the app, login page appear in first state. Then I click the login button, browser path changing but view not rendering. If I press the browser refresh button after login. Page rendering correctly. After that next time till I click refresh button on the browser everything works fine. If someone give me advice, I'll much appreciate.

Comment: Remove the `exact` property from the rest of the links, also add a generic 404 router to debug further like this -> `<Route component={GenericNotFound} />`

Comment: Now it's redirect me to `notFound` page I added. If I remove this `notFound` page then empty page showing.

Comment: Then it means the component is not found but the routing is done properly. There could also be problems inside the component iteself, Share more code so that i can debug or check you console too.

Comment: I don't think the component has error in itself because when I click the refresh button on browser, the page is showing. browser path is : `localhost:300/home` while I click the refresh button. So component is working fine.

Comment: I have the same issue did you find a solution ?
i even tried installing the `history` package and using it with `react-router-dom` and still not working. and in another react-redux app i have a login form and i should redirect after `dispatch` and it's not even changing the URL in this app, and there are no errors in the console.

Comment: Hello @HassanAzzam, I didn't found a feasible solution for this structure. I found a privateRouting component example on google. I implemented this solution to my app. If you search on google with terms of 'react private routing' , you will find many result. I hope one of them can be feasible for your app.

Comment: For my application, the same problem happened, and this was related to version 5 of the history. Downgrading to version 4, it worked perfectly.

Comment: Same thing here, blank page is displayed when upgrading to 5.0.0 any solutions?

Comment: [React router not working property on latest, v5, version of "history"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65985293/2873538)